# How to reliably detect network status using React Native / Expo CLI

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to detect connections status on my application to enable offline playback. Currently I call the function below, CheckConnectivity using Network from Expo, but it only seems to return true even when the phone is in airplane mode. If there is any way to test an application’s offline functionality before building in Expo that would be extremely useful to me as well as I’ve had to wait between builds to test and it is very time consuming.

```
    const CheckConnectivity = async () => {
        //Check if the internet is connected - just do a get request to pwt if it fails wifi is off
        let networkStatus = await Network.getNetworkStateAsync();
        if(networkStatus.isConnected)
        {
            await dispatch(courseActions.setWiFiStatus( true ));
            console.log("online...");

        }
        else 
        {
            await dispatch(courseActions.setWiFiStatus( false ));
            console.log("ofline...");
            //Route to offline screen
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetInfo` would be the module for that.
Here the [link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo).

Fetch info by doing:

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

NetInfo.fetch().then(info => console.log(info.isConnected));
```

Or subscribe to changes:

```
// Subscribe
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```

Check out the docs you can do more cool stuff like checking connection types.